# ARM Change string to different length? Ghidra, Ida Pro

Tags: arm, reverse-engineering, ida, ghidra

I'm trying to translate compiled script to native language. I'm using ida pro and ghidra, but I've stuck on problem. I can change string values to any, if string length is same. But if string length is bigger or smaller, I have problems. I'm newbie here and can't post photos, so I will upload them to imgur. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE2PQ.jpg

When I insert additional byte to current string, IDA not wants to open file and says error. I understand, probably somewhere it is stored that string length, but I can't find anything. And at all, maybe it is not possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find it helpful to ask at the reverse engineering SE, although you might find answers here as well.  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> probably somewhere it is stored that string length, but I can't find anything

From the screenshot it looks like they are NUL-terminated strings so the length is not stored but determined by checking for the NULL byte. Shorter strings can be inserted by inserting a NULL byte earlier in the string, but for longer ones you would have to do more (like move stuff around) so there's room for them. This might be really time consuming (would need to update references to those)